# JS in node-red : Arrays, Objects, and how to get to them

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, node-red

I have a function node:

```
PoolVarAuto = global.get('PoolVarAuto');
PoolVarPump = global.get('PoolVarPump');

msg.payload  = [{'var':'PoolVarPump', 'val': PoolVarPump} , {'var': 'PoolVarAuto', 'val': PoolVarAuto}] ;
return msg;
```

This outputs 2 arrays, with an object each. But, I cannot access a variable in one of them, as such:

```
msg.payload[0].var
```

What am I doing wrong? 
(corrected the payload spelling in this version after the help, tx !.)

Comment: payoad - that's obviously a typo, but why should msg be something different than on assignment?

Comment: If you fix the typo, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/34ymenqe/ Note that the JavaScript engines in obsolete browsers like IE8 may not like your using `var` as an unquoted property name (anything vaguely up-to-date will be fine with it, it was allowed in the 5th edition JavaScript specification in December 2009).

Comment: Thanks and Thanks ! <feel like an idiot !>